# Meteor static content

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to add icons ([this icons](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)) to my meteor project placing them into 'app/public' but it freezes my app at starting process:

"Building the application /"

Also tried to place them into 'client/lib', but get's the same result

Using:
Meteor 1.3.2.4

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Create a new project

`meteor create materialtest`

We're doing this to ensure there's no package incompatibility issues, and isolate the simplest issue we can (Meteor with Material Icons).

#### 2. Add a single file

/client/head.html

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Meteor should pick up the head in this file and render it.  Right now afaik this is the only way to put stuff in the head with Meteor 1.3.

#### 3. See if it runs

`meteor`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! So, only CDN ? What about good old way to load everything that client needs into static folder through Bower ?

Comment: You can add the resource file to [/public](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) and load from there.  I just suggested from CDN to get a quick test going.

Comment: It work's perfectly, but I still have this issue with freezing server when I place files (43mb of pictures + jsons mainly) into '/public'

Comment: I'm guessing most of that 43mb is reference and not meant to be served.  Try putting only what you need to server in `/public`; I'm thinking maybe the meteor dev server is getting overwhelmed.  If you want to store the rest in your repository you can put it under `/private`.  You can read more @ https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories.